# Tool to benchmark Sqlite, MongoDB and InfluxDB for embedded systems

Tags: database, mongodb, sqlite, embedded-systems, arm

So I searched Databases for Embedded systems and ARM processors for data from sensors. I selected 3-4 databases, Sqlite, MongoDB, InfluxDB and maybe Prometheus. I would like to compare them so I would like to benchmark them, is there a tool for that ? 
I founded PromBench for Prometheus, Inch for InfluxDB for the moment but each of these tools are made for one database.

Comment: These databases are completely different conceptually, so it is a bit like benchmarking a carrot versus a book: Do you want to benchmark the proportion of vitamin or the number of pages? A common benchmark could compare the weight of the carrot vs the weight of the book. What kind of benchmark would be useful to you? A benchmark testing for all SQL operations will completely eliminate MongoDB, while a test for blob throughput will eliminate SQLite.

Comment: I want to test the quantity of storage available, the writing throughput and the latency